# Invalid column name 'Age'

Tags: sql

[image]

Hi, I have created a column Age where its calculating the date difference and converting the value into integer.
Next, I have created another column with Age Trend where I wrote a clause

```
case when Age < 120 then '<120'
        else '>120' end 'Age Trend'
```

for this its throwing the **Invalid column name 'Age'** error.

could anyone explain me how to fix it.

Thanks,
Rama

Comment: Posting images of technical information like code and error messages, instead of formatted text, is the fastest way I've seen here other than spam for your question to be downvoted and then closed or ignored.

Comment: where is data table data table need to clarify this problem

Comment: For example, I was about to answer this, and when I went to copy/paste code from your question to my answer I saw again it was an image, so this wasn't possible. And as it's about midnight where I am I decided it wasn't worth retyping things. Therefore no answer yet.

Comment: Please comment add sql text query.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Please always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS. Most DBMS would raise an error here: `as int) 'Age',` and here: `end 'Age Trend',`. Single quotes denote string literals in SQL. Don't use them for names / aliases. Use proper name delimiters, which is the double quote in standard SQL, or better avoid them completely by not using names that contain blanks or other characters that must be quoted. `else '> 120' end as age_trend` would be my preference.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 3):

Please replace real query for 'Age'.

'Age' = >  'cast(DATEDIFF(dd,[First Detected],[Last Detected]) as int)'

```
cast(DATEDIFF(dd,[First Detected],[Last Detected]) as int) 'Age',
case when 
cast(DATEDIFF(dd,[First Detected],[Last Detected]) as int) < 120 then '<120'
else '>120' end 'Age Trend',
```

Comment: Added comment description.

Answer (score 3):

You can not use aliased column in the same level `Select` query. Either you need to use the same calculation again to make the 'Age Trend' column or you can use `Sub Query` like below :

```
select *, case when Age < 120 then '<120' else '>120' end Age_Trend 
from 
    (select [port], cast(DATEDIFF(dd, [First Detected], [Last Detected]) as int) Age
     from yourTable) AS Table1
```